# How to define rules with Bolt to allow modifying a child of a type without providing all the other fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my app I keep user data in a firebase database. The authenticated users can change most of the properties there. But there is one (`score`) property that I want to be able to change from an external service **only**. User's can read its value but must not change it.

I'm using [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) to define security rules on my database.

If my `Bolt` file looks like this:

```
type User {
  name: String
  score: Score
}

type Score extends Number | Null {
  validate() { canChangeScore() }
}

canChangeScore() { auth.canChangeScore === true }

path / {
  read() { true }
  path /users/{id} is User {
    write() { auth.uid == id }
  }
}
```

then it will give me these rules:

```
 1  {
 2    "rules": {
 3      "users": {
 4        "$id": {
 5          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name'])",
 6          "name": {
 7            ".validate": "newData.isString()"
 8          },
 9          "score": {
10            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && auth.canChangeScore == true"
11          },
12          "$other": {
13            ".validate": "false"
14          },
15          ".write": "auth.uid == $id"
16        }
17      },
18      ".read": "true"
19    }
20  }
```

Now when I try to update the `score` field from the external service with a function like:

```
function incUserScore(userId) {
  const scoreRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(userId).child('score');
  scoreRef.transaction(current => (current || 0) + 1)
}
```

I get `permission_denied` error because of the line `5` in the `json` rules as I don't provide the `name` field.

Is there any way of expressing such an intent in Bolt without making all the User fields Nullable or extracting the `scores` to their own path?

Comment: You might find [this discussion](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/issues/127) useful. Particularly, [this](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/issues/127#issuecomment-176327986) comment.

Comment: If the user isn't supposed to change the score i suggest you seperate the score and user data. With your current rules the user can change the score because[rules cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade)

Comment: @AndréKool you're right. I've updated the question so that the `Score` uses `validate()` instead of `write()` rule.